# Вывод случайного значения из бд?

Tags: python, telegram

Вот так я добавляю в базу данных id, username

```
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
    id INTEGER,
    username TEXT
  )""")
  connect.commit()

  people_id = call.message.chat.id
  people_us = call.from_user.username
  cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = {people_id}")
  data = cursor.fetchone()
  if data is None :
    user_id = call.message.chat.id
    username =  call.from_user.username
    cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO login_id  VALUES ("{user_id}" , "{username}") """)
    connect.commit()
  else:
    pass
```

Вот мой код который должен выводить данные из username но выводит из id

```
bd = list(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login_id ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;").fetchone())
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, bd)
```

Comment: `SELECT id ...` по этой строчке вы решили, что должен выводится `username`? Логично

Answer (score 0):

Раз Вы используете в последнем запросе `SELECT * ...`, то выводится список сформированный из записи БД, в котором сначала `id`, потом `username`. Используйте `SELECT username ...`, если Вам `id` вообще не нужен.

Comment: Оказывается проблема была не в коде а в консоли. Я так и делал но почему писало ошибку, перешел на обычную консоль все заработало